# DataGridView SetFocus after CellEndEdit

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, desktop

I used the `CellEndEdit` event, after editing the cell value I press the Enter Key, then the cell focus moves down.

I want the focus to go back at the original Cell where I edited the value.

I used many ways, but failed.

```
Private Sub DataGridVie1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridVie1.CellEndEdit
   '...
   '....editing codes here...to input and validate values...
   '...
   '...
   '...before the End If of the procedure I put this values
   DataGridVie1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Selected = True
   DataGridVie1.CurrentCell = DataGridVie1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
   'DataGridVie1.BeginEdit(False) '''DID NOT apply this because it cause to edit again.
End If
```

I don't know the real code when after edit or after a ENTER KEY the focus is back in the original Cell that was edited.

Because everytime I HIT the ENTER KEY, it directly go down to the next Cell.

Whats the code to reposition the focus back to the original Cell edited.

I know the `EditingControlShowing` method but I don't think I have to used that method to get what I wanted too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: define 3 variables.
One to memorize if an edit operation has been made, the other 2 to store row and column indexes of the last edited cell:

```
Private flag_cell_edited As Boolean
Private currentRow As Integer
Private currentColumn As Integer
```

When an edit operation occurs you store coordinates of edited cell and set your flag to true inside `CellEndEdit` event handler:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    flag_cell_edited = True
    currentColumn = e.ColumnIndex
    currentRow = e.RowIndex
End Sub
```

Then in `SelectionChanged` event handler you set `DataGridView`'s `CurrentCell` property to the last edited cell using `currentRow` and `currentColumn` variables to undo default cell focus change:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    If flag_cell_edited Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(currentColumn, currentRow)
        flag_cell_edited = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i need not to think for this method because you already provided. thank you and to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Andrea's idea but using a `DataGridViewCell` to handle things:

```
Private LastCell As DataGridViewCell = Nothing

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    LastCell = DataGridView1.CurrentCell
End Sub 

Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    If LastCell IsNot Nothing Then
        DataGridView.CurrentCell = LastCell
        LastCell = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```