# Set the current to its position if the value is empty in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cell

First is the current cell have a value, and then I will delete the value to empty the cell. Then I will press enter, Then is my code for preventing the current cell to go to the new row if the value of the cell is empty:

```
  Private Sub dvList_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dvList.CellEndEdit

    dvList.CurrentCell = dvList.Item(1, dvList.CurrentRow.Index - 1)

End Sub
```

This is not working, if I press enter, its going to the next row and not to the current cell position.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17511317/909742) post out, maybe it proves useful

Answer (score 0):

Try Cell_Validating Event

sample code :

```
If e.FormattedValue.ToString.Trim =vbnullstring then
   e.Cancel=True
   Exit sub
End if
```